# Configure OHS Weblogic 12c / Apache to support TLSv2 only

Tags: oracle, ssl, https, weblogic, tls1.2

And thanks for your help and I would like to know if someone has faced this issue, I don't success to configure my SSL configuration for OHS, it seems that TLSV1.2 only doesn't work .

My OHS is embedeed with a weblogic 12C

See below my configuration

```
###################################################################
# Oracle HTTP Server mod_ossl configuration file: ssl.conf        #
###################################################################

# The Listen directive below has a comment preceding it that is used
# by tooling which updates the configuration.  Do not delete the comment.
#[Listen] OHS_SSL_PORT
Listen 8443

<IfModule ossl_module>
##
##  SSL Global Context
##
##  All SSL configuration in this context applies both to
##  the main server and all SSL-enabled virtual hosts.
##

#
#   Some MIME-types for downloading Certificates and CRLs
    AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
    AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

#   Inter-Process Session Cache:
#   Configure the SSL Session Cache: First the mechanism 
#   to use, second the expiring timeout (in seconds) and third
#   the mutex to be used.
    SSLSessionCache "shmcb:${ORACLE_INSTANCE}/servers/${COMPONENT_NAME}/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
    SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
    <IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
      Mutex pthread ssl-cache
    </IfModule>

##
## SSL Virtual Host Context
##
#[VirtualHost] OHS_SSL_VH
<VirtualHost *:8443> 
  <IfModule ossl_module>
   #  SSL Engine Switch:
   #  Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
   SSLEngine on

   #  Client Authentication (Type):
   #  Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
   #  none, optional and require.
   SSLVerifyClient None

   #  SSL Protocol Support:
   #  Configure usable SSL/TLS protocol versions.
   SSLProtocol +TLSv1.2 nzos_Version_3_0_With_2_0_Hello nzos_Version_3_0

   #  SSL Cipher Suite:
   #  List the ciphers that the client is permitted to negotiate.
   # SSL Certificate Revocation List Check
   # Valid values are On and Off

SSLCipherSuite ALL

SSLCRLCheck Off

   #Path to the wallet
SSLWallet "/data/as/Certificates/OHS"
        
   <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
   </FilesMatch>

   <Directory "${ORACLE_INSTANCE}/config/fmwconfig/components/${COMPONENT_TYPE}/instances/${COMPONENT_NAME}/cgi-bin">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
   </Directory>

   BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

See below the errors when I tried to connect with the URL ?

```
2021-02-04T19:12:18.2523+01:00] [OHS] [ERROR:32] [OH99999] [ossl] [client_id: 172.21.0.68] [host_id: lpacs122] [host_addr: 172.21.20.79] [pid: 29658] [user: as] [VirtualHost: localhost:8443] OHS:2079 Client SSL handshake error, nzos_Handshake returned 29039(server localhost:8443)
[2021-02-04T19:12:18.2523+01:00] [OHS] [ERROR:32] [OH99999] [ossl] [host_id: lpacs122] [host_addr: 172.21.20.79] [pid: 29658] [user: as] [VirtualHost: localhost:8443] OHS:2171 NZ Library Error: SSL negotiation error [Hint: too restrictive SSLCipherSuite]
```

Does someone has faced this issue ?

Many Thanks for yor help